# Does PIG have NOT IN clause

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm trying like

```
select * from A where A.ID NOT IN (select id from B) (in sql)

filtersource= FILTER source BY ID NOT(destination.ID)
```

How to do NOT IN clause or some other technique to keen out the extra records present in one table using pig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this in PIG like:

```
filtersource= FILTER source BY NOT ID IN (your condition or joined field);
```

example:

```
HIVE> select * from table where id NOT IN ('1','2','3');

grunt> A = LOAD 'db.table' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader() AS (id:int, value:chararray);
grunt> B = FILTER A BY NOT id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Hi Rijul and Ronak thanks for the response, I have tried with the comment filtersource= FILTER sourcenew BY NOT ID (destnew.ID);, but I have got an error ERROR 1070: Could not resolve ID using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.], any idea how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Rijulsahu's answer,  you can also use [`MATCHES`](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Comparison+Operators) - Regular expression matching that Uses the [Java format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for regular expressions.

`BY NOT(ID MATCHES [123])`